# Keylogging in keyboard drivers possible?

Tags: security, privacy

I found this article: https://www.hackread.com/chinese-keyboard-developer-spies-on-user-through-built-in-keylogger/ , that disturbingly details how a keyboard manufacturer logs keystrokes and sends data back to the manufacturer.

So would it be possible for keyboards or usb switching devices like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01N6GD9JO/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza to record and send keystrokes without software downloaded from the manufacturer websites. Can the "plug and play" drivers alone do this?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is possible. If you're too suspicious about some external device that you're using you can try and see if your machine is sending packets to unusual websites (for example with Wireshark). Another thing you could do is see if there are unusual tasks in the task manager.

There is probably another way of figuring out how to detect keyloggers from hardware but that's the first idea that came to mind.

Although it is possible that malicious manufacturers have keyloggers in their products, I would find it unlikely to be the case in trusted/known manufacturers.

I've linked a post from another forum that might help you as well:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158805/how-to-detect-a-keylogger-in-a-usb-keyboard-can-a-usb-keyboard-host-a-keylogger?newreg=d7d319783eed48c099520021ecdc10d7

Comment: @jezza562 You're welcome. If you don't have any more questions or concerns, feel free to accept my answer.